# Where do I view information harvested from Facebook Login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

First of all, let me point that I have only used Facebook Apps and Facebook Analytics for the first time about two days ago and my knowledge of code, app building etc is very very minimal.

I have recently added Facebook Login to a webpage of mine, which is working great. 
[FB Login working property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beHBn.png)

The page with Facebook Login on - https://valdezwright.com/access

The only problem is, I cannot figure out where to VIEW this information.

All I need to view for my own purposes are email/name/maybe some other bits, but I cant find where to find it in, for example, a nice accessable spreadsheet or something similar.

I have Facebook Analytics.

Can anyone help me with this please? I'd be most appreciative as I'm currently pulling my hair out!

Thanks

Comment: You need to store it somewhere if you want to view it. And we have no idea if/where you store it

Comment: WizKid - this is news to me thank you. What are my options? What should I search for in Google?

Comment: When the user logins in you make an API call to get the data and then you store it